# Automatically update Sonar exclusions after refactor

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, static-code-analysis

My project currently uses the `<sonar.exclusions>` property in `pom.xml` to exclude certain files from Sonar metrics. This works well except when an excluded file is moved or renamed. When this happens the path is not updated in the pom and the file is no longer excluded. I use IntelliJ which is much better at updating references to files than Eclipse (for example it will update a `serverless.yml` if the `handler` class is moved/renamed) but even it doesn't update `<sonar.exclusions>`. I wonder if there's an annotation that could be added to a file that has the same effect or another approach which is more amenable to refactoring?

Comment: What are these files you're excluding, and why are they excluded? There are `nosonar` markers you can put in some files, but this may not suit what you're looking for.

Comment: There are various types of classes which are excluded. Some are simple POJOs which are used with Google AutoValue so there's no need for tests, others are modules for Google Dagger. There are a handful of others but these are the majority. There's not one specific part of the classes that shouldn't be checked so I don't think `nosonar` is suitable here.

Comment: Did you look at `@SuppressWarnings({<code1>, <code2>, ...})`

Comment: That works for individual warnings but the file is still included in test coverage metrics which is not the case when using `<sonar.exclusions>` and is the behaviour I wish to keep.